# i want to reduce the space between these elements

Tags: html, css

I want for my h4,h1 and p elements to be more close to each other, but I don't understand how I should go about doing it even after a little research. Trying to make my first project look half decent
here is my HTML

```css
body {
    background-color: #88BDBC
}

main {
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    margin-top: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Antonio', sans-serif;
}

h4 {
      color: white; 
      border: 15px;
      background-color: #2F4F4F;
      display: inline;
  }
h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PORTFOLIO</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Antonio:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./base.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
      <h4>beginner front-end developer</h4>
      <h1>i'm x</h1>
      <p>hello my name is x and this is my portfolio</p>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p,h4` and `h1` has default `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` property. simply change it to whatever you want:

```css
body {
    background-color: #88BDBC
}

main {
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    margin-top: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Antonio', sans-serif;
}

h4 {
      color: white; 
      border: 15px;
      background-color: #2F4F4F;
      display: inline;
      margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
      
  }
h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PORTFOLIO</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Antonio:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./base.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
      <h4>beginner front-end developer</h4>
      <h1>i'm x</h1>
      <p>hello my name is x and this is my portfolio</p>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see their [default values here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

Comment: thank you so much! i thought it had something to do with the margins but I didn't know exactly how to proceed.

Comment: @Danesinhell :) plz mark as accepted